# how to use box api in asp.net web application

Tags: c#, box

I am trying to use box api in an asp.net web application.

Based on the search there are two options to access box account;

1. By downloading the [Box.V2 package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Box.V2/) using below link containing the required dlls and use that in our application
2. By using [Box SDK](https://github.com/box/box-windows-sdk-v2) containing code and reference that inside our application. Using this approach we can debug the Box.V2 code by adding the project to our solution.

Correct me if I am wrong.

So, I am trying to implement the second approach. Can someone help me move forward by specifying the steps to be taken, minimum .net framework requirement, etc.

Comment: Based on the logs Method not found: 'Void System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.set_AutomaticDecompression(System.Net.DecompressionMethods)'

Comment: I don't see any code. Can you help with them?

Comment: Please let me know if you have used Box SDK and what approach you have taken. I can use the same.

Answer (score 3):

Good question, GitHub samples does not mention about the Web (Asp.Net). 
It's possible and it looks pretty easy to do once you figure out the the way,
I have seen some answers for Windows apps trying to manually build the authorization URLs etc, but there is an easier way to do it.

Here's how to do it with OAuth,

1. Install nuget

> PM> Install-Package Box.V2

2. Get the Authcode (this is what's been missing in most examples)

   ```
   public async Task<ActionResult> Connect()
   {
       var clientId = "xxxxx";
       var clientSecret = "xxxxxx";
       var redirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost:xxxx/Home/AuthCallBackAsync");//Your call back URL

       var config = new BoxConfig(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUri);

       return Redirect(config.AuthCodeUri.ToString());
   }
   ```

Interesting thing is that the "config" object generates the AuthCodeUri. 
This will redirect the user to Consent screen and ask the user to sign in. Once the user "Grants Access" you will get the "Authcode" for your call back URL which can be used to generate accesstoken.

3. Handle the Auth Callback response

   ```
   public async Task<ActionResult> AuthCallbackAsync()
   {
      NameValueCollection parms = Request.QueryString;
      var authCode = parms["code"]
      //Get "config" - you can store this in session or in a cache.
      var config = new BoxConfig(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUri);
      var client = new BoxClient(config);

      await client.Auth.AuthenticateAsync(authCode);
      //Now you will get the accesstoken and refresh token 
      var accessToken = client.Auth.Session.AccessToken;
      var refreshToken = client.Auth.Session.RefreshToken;

      //Ready to consume the API
      var user = await client.UsersManager.GetCurrentUserInformationAsync();

       -------More Api Calls--- 

   }
   ```